# Weird Symbol PHP â€“ instead of -

Tags: symbols

Hey, well I'm having a problem and this weird symbol is showing up

â€“

it's suppose to be a " - " but for some reason it's not doing that,anyone got any ideas why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an encoding problem. You might be reading some Unicode text, but it's being interpreted as ASCII instead.